# Node.js Is this a global variable or an environemnt variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading the source code of this [project](https://github.com/emmenko/redux-react-router-async-example), in the **package.json** file, it has a line:

```
"scripts":{
    "start:devtools": "npm run build && DEVTOOLS=true node server.js"
}
```

Later, in the **configureStore.js**, it is used like this

```
/* global __DEVTOOLS__ */

if (__DEVTOOLS__) { ... }
```

I am new to node, and I would like to know:

1. In the package.json, `DEVTOOLS=true`, is this section setting an environment variable?
2. What does the `/* global __DEVTOOLS__ */` do at the top of configureStore.js?

Comment: Well I can tell you that `/* global __DEVTOOLS__ */` does nothing, since `/*` and `*/` respectively mark the beginning and ending of a multi-line comment.

Comment: `/* global __DEVTOOLS__ */` tells `eslint` that `__DEVTOOLS__` is a global variable, so it won't raise `"variable is not defined"` error.

Comment: As for `__DEVTOOLS__` variable, it's defined in [webpack config file](https://github.com/emmenko/redux-react-router-async-example/blob/master/webpack.config.js).

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny so `DEVTOOLS=true` is how to set environment variables in the shell?

Comment: @Cheng yep, it is how to set environment variables for the current shell command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"scripts":{
    "start:devtools": "npm run build && DEVTOOLS=true node server.js"
}
```

With this line, `DEVTOOLS` will be an environment variable. You can access it with `process.env.DEVTOOLS`.

Webpack use this variable when initializing some pluging and some config. So it will become the `__DEVTOOLS__` global variable.

`/* global __DEVTOOLS__ */`

This line is just a comment. So, alone, it does nothing. But the instruction `global` is used by javascript parser/checker like `eslint` or `jslint`. It tells to the checker that `__DEVTOOLS__` is a provided global variable so it won't crash reading it.

Comment: I thought `export DEVTOOLS=true` is the way to set environment variables, how come there is no `export`? Also, DEVTOOLS  and `__DEVTOOLS__`  is the same variable?

Comment: You have multiples way to define an environment variables. The line you see in `scripts` is an npm command. In Webpack code, `process.env.DEVTOOLS` become the `__DEVTOOLS__` global variable.